# python 3.6.1 opencv 3.3.1 cv2.imshow() not displaying image

Tags: python, opencv

The issue: `imshow()` doesn't display anything.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img_rgb = cv2.imread('opencv-template-matching-python-tutorial.jpg')
img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img_rgb, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

template = cv2.imread('opencv-template-for-matching.jpg',0)
w, h = template.shape[::-1]

res = cv2.matchTemplate(img_gray,template,cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
threshold = 0.8
loc = np.where( res >= threshold)

for pt in zip(*loc[::-1]):
    cv2.rectangle(img_rgb, pt, (pt[0] + w, pt[1] + h), (0,255,255), 2)

cv2.imshow('Detected',img_rgb)
```

---

Another example of displaying image does not working correctly neither. Cannot exit, only stills displayed, not the video.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0) 
cv2.startWindowThread()
while(1):
   _, frame = cap.read()
   cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
   k = cv2.waitKey(0) & 0xFF
   if k == 27:
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
cap.release()
```

I'm using:

- python 3.6.1
- opencv 3.3.1
- Windows 10

Comment: missing `cv2.waitKey()` in first snippet, and  should be `cv2.waitKey(1)` in second snippet

Answer (score 0):

You need to give time for the `window` to `open`, and a method for `closing` it.

The usual way of of doing this with `openCV` is with `.waitKey(n)`. This function will `halt` the `execution` of the `program` for `n` `milliseconds` (`0` being `infinite`) or until the `user` presses a `key`.

So in the first `snippet`, you just need to add the following line to the end:

cv2.waitKey(0)

---

In the second `snippet`, you need to change the `line`:

```
k = cv2.waitKey(0) & 0xFF
```

to

```
k = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
```

so that the `loop` can continue to `run` (as the `0` waits for ever).

Comment: Joe Iddon, Thansk fr the reply and useful information.

Comment: Joe Iddon, Thank you for the reply and useful information. 
Both examples are much more functional, but not completely fixed.     
The second example is displaying the expected image results, but the only way to gain control back is to manual close the image window via the red X.  No keyboard action seems to regain control back to python.  
The first example - Video capturing, does now display live video, but has no means to exit the program without killing the command line editor.   Thank again for any suggestions.

Comment: Try removing the `&0xFF` from the end of the second one and you need to add `cv2.destroyAllWindows()` at the end of the first one after the wait key (sorry I forgot that). It should then work, please up-vote and accept when it does and if you have problems, I'm not sure what else to suggest as that works for me and is the standard way of doing it...

Comment: Joe, thanks for the second cut at the issue.  Still not resolved, but will be glad to give you the upvote as I am in better shape thanks to your feedback.  I think my issue may have to do with the flle "digits.py" something with line 107 int vs float?? my open CV cv2.destroyAllWindows(), and cv2.waitKey(0) do not seem to work correctly yet.

Comment: Keep trying, not much more anyone can do from this position though without seeing the full picture... (Btw, you don't have significant rep to up-vote, only accept so it didn't do anything) hope you get it going eventually! Good luck